# Spring and Soap client, use pooling?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

I'm creating a Spring backend app, which expose mostly rest entrypoints.

This application connects to various remote services, including several SOAP webservices.

In order to answer requests with nice performances, is that a good idea to create a pool for SOAP client services ? Using CommonsPoolTargetSource ?

Is there some ressources about accomplishing that sort of spool, usung Java based config in a Spring boot environnement ?

I'm also thinking about implementing an EIP bus using Spring Integration ; does the "pool part" can be accomplished within it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you misunderstood that `AbstractPoolingTargetSource`  purpose:

```
 * Abstract base class for pooling {@link org.springframework.aop.TargetSource}
 * implementations which maintain a pool of target instances, acquiring and
 * releasing a target object from the pool for each method invocation.
 * This abstract base class is independent of concrete pooling technology;
 * see the subclass {@link CommonsPool2TargetSource} for a concrete example.
```

With Spring WS (and Spring Integration WS adapters) you don't need any `pooling`. Those components for Client infrastructure are `singleton`s, so they are reusable and thread-safe.

I fully don't understand what you are going to pool there...

As well as not sure can be pooled in the EIP bus. I don't tell already that it's not a pattern any more with Spring Integration in hands.